# bootstrap table extension show all columns (hideAllColumns or showAllColumns) not working

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-table

I am following the table document
http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/

I just want to note that when I use this (showAllColumns or hideAllColumns) for the button with this code

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable('showAllColumns');
```

There is an error for this: "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'I')

My goal is to close all columns and open selected columns.
closing individual columns is working but not efficient

```
$('#table')bootstrapTable('hideColumn', 'column1');
$('#table')bootstrapTable('hideColumn', 'column2');
. . .
```

and show other columns

```
$('#table')bootstrapTable('showColumn', 'column11');
$('#table')bootstrapTable('showColumn', 'column12');
```

There is other post about

```
$('#show_all').on('click', function(){
  $('table th').show();
})
```

but that does not work for me .

anybody test this and see if it is working?
example, I added the code here to the Reset button but it does not work

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable('hideAllColumns');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/12301/

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I receive the same error...

Answer (score 0):

The official website has an [online editor](https://live.bootstrap-table.com/), where you may to load ready-made examples.

Including your case:

https://live.bootstrap-table.com/example/methods/show-hide-all-columns.html

First, add buttons:

```
<div id="toolbar">
  <button id="show_all" class="btn btn-secondary">Show All Columns</button>
  <button id="hide_all" class="btn btn-secondary">Hide All Columns</button>
  <button id="hide_price" class="btn btn-secondary">Hide Price Column</button>
</div>
```

And init table:

```
<table
  id="table"
  data-toggle="table"
  data-toolbar="#toolbar"
  data-height="460"
  data-show-columns="true"
  data-pagination="true"
  data-side-pagination="server"
  data-url="https://examples.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/bootstrap_table/data">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true" data-switchable="false">ID</th>
      <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Item Name</th>
      <th data-field="price" data-sortable="true">Item Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Then you create button actions:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#show_all').click(function() {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable('showAllColumns')
  })

  $('#hide_all').click(function() {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable('hideAllColumns')
  })
  
  $('#hide_price').click(function() {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable('hideColumn', 'price')
  })
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kaperusov/1b8oruf9/5/

Comment: Thanks for taking my recommendation. (Please understand that I am not in the position to vote on your answer. I lack the technical understanding.)